# AttributedStringのlinkのアクションを別のアクションにoverrideしたい

Tags: swift, swiftui

AttributedStringのlinkを設定した際に、デフォルトではSafariで開かれるようになっていますが、このアクションを自分で設定する(override)する方法はあるでしょうか？

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var attributedString: AttributedString {
    var attributedString = AttributedString("Apple(URL)")
    attributedString.link = URL(string: "https://apple.com")
    return attributedString
  }

  var body: some View {
    Text(attributedString)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in print(url); return .handled }`で可能のようです。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70726761/15098239